# pulse_output failed to play: suspended

Tags: pulseaudio, mpd

I have mpd running as a system service and as user `mpd`. Since mpd is a system service and pulse audio is session-based, I have to stream music from mpd to the currently active pulse session daemon. This is done using the `module-native-protocol-tcp module` configured with `auth-anonymous=1 auth-cookie-enabled=0 listen=0.0.0.0` (loose, I know, but for testing purposes)

The output in mpd.conf looks like this:

```
audio_output {                                                                   
  type    "pulse"                                                                
  name    "My (loopback) Pulse Output"                                           
  server  "localhost"                                                            
}
```

Now when I run a song in mpd it complains:

```
pulse_output: "My (loopback) Pulse Output" [pulse] failed to play: suspended
output: Failed to open audio output
```

What is wrong here? Is this a bug?

What I tried :
Running as my user (systemd)
Running as my user (systemd) and set the user in mpd.conf
Running as root and set the user in mpd.conf
Setting the exact sink name

Comment: Have you considered running the pulse daemon as a system service?

Comment: Yes, but It is strongly discouraged by the developers.

Comment: Related : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245639/mpd-and-chrome-cant-both-play-audio-at-the-same-time?rq=1

Comment: I had a very similar problem and this solved my problem : http://askubuntu.com/questions/555103/mpd-with-pulseaudio

Answer (score 0):

You seem to understand what is going on better than I do, but I had the same error message, and the problem disappeared following the instructions on [this wiki page](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/PulseAudio#For_Distros_where_MPD_is_running_as_its_own_user) (also relayed at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555103/mpd-with-pulseaudio)) :

Using the same `mpd.conf` as you do.

> Uncomment the following lines from /etc/pulse/default.pa (you might need to add the part which specified the IP address to the line):

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 # IP of localhost
```