# MPD and Chrome can't both play audio at the same time

Tags: chrome, alsa, pulseaudio, mpd

I use MPD to stream music, but noticed that I often could not get any sound.  I finally figured out that if I quit the Chrome web browser, then playback would continue.

This is the relevant section of my mpd.conf file,

```
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "ma Device"
    mixer_type      "software"    # optional
    dsd_usb         "yes"
}
```

It is also the case that if MPD is playing music, then Chrome can't play any type of video file - I click play on a youtube video and it will hang until I pause MPD.  Then when Chrome is playing the video, the output of a 
`fuser -fv /dev/snd/*` command is

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  jason      2085 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   jason      2085 F...m pulseaudio
```

The `pcmC0D0p` appears to be Chrome, and `controlC0` is MPD.  Sometimes playback on MPD will continue when I stop the video, but sometimes the `pcmC0D0p` will stay active until I quit Chrome.

Bottom line, MPD will not play while `pcmC0D0p` is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use PulseAudio's mechanism of sharing the sound device, all applications must use PulseAudio.

You have to [configure MPD to use PulseAudio](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/PulseAudio).

Comment: Following the instructions in that page, and then restarting, I now have MPD working no matter what.  And now the youtube video will start and play just fine, but the sound will not work on the youtube.  Even if I stop the MPD service, still no sound from youtube

Comment: It could have something to do with [this](http://i.imgur.com/hzC54qa.png), there is no output device listed for sound any more